# Сверстать линии разной длины

Tags: вёрстка, css

Как можно сверстать эти линии разной длины в списке?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eg1ia.png]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пример тут: ( http://jsfiddle.net/L2ya3buj/ ). Не судите строго за SCSS.

```
<div class="counter-list">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span class="key">
                 Код
            </span>
            <span class="value">
                 4607003998708
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

.counter-list {
    ul {
        li {
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
            &:after {
                content:'';
                display: block;;
                overflow: hidden;
                height: 14px;
                border-bottom: 1px dotted #666
            }
            .key {
                display: block;
                float: left;
                z-index: 2;
                padding-right: 2px;
            }
            .value {
                display: block;
                float: right;
                z-index: 2;
                padding-left: 2px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ага, спасибо, мне уже как раз такой вариант,  с использование псевдоэлемента  after пришел в голову.

Comment: Используйте вот такой вариант: http://jsfiddle.net/L2ya3buj/1/ его хитрость в том что не нужно закрашивать background у элементов и можно использовать когда задний фон "неравномерный"

Comment: Да, спасибо большое, его и использую.

Answer (score 3):

На основе вот этой статьи: **[DOT LEADERS](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/leaders.en.html)**

Разметка:

```
<ul class="leaders">
    <li>
        <span>Однокомнатный стандарт</span>
        <span>1.500 руб/сут</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Однокомнатный</span>
        <span>2.000 руб/сут</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Двухкомнатный стандарт</span>
        <span>4.500 руб/сут</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Стили:

```
ul.leaders {
    max-width: 40em;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    list-style: none
}
ul.leaders li:before {
    float: left;
    width: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    content:"____________________"
            "____________________"
            "____________________"
            "____________________"
}
ul.leaders span:first-child {
    padding-right: 0.33em;
    background: white
}
ul.leaders span + span {
    float: right;
    padding-left: 0.33em;
    background: white
}
```

Итог

[image]

**[Ссылка на пример](http://jsfiddle.net/dzL4rz5s/)**

Answer (score 3):

Если известно то, что ширины достаточно для того, чтобы вместить строчку целиком, без переносов, то вполне подойдет вариант с табличкой: http://jsfiddle.net/m6v783Ld/

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="row__term">Such a nice term</div>
    <div class="row__dots"></div>
    <div class="row__key">1. 01</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.row {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.row__term {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.row__dots {
    display: table-cell;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}

.row__key {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Есть ещё вот такой вариант на основе [этой статьи](http://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/71512/):

```css
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
.product-item {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.container-stroke {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.element {
  float: left;
  min-width: 50px;
  max-width: 310px;
}
.stretch-element {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 1%;
}
.line {
  height: 14px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
}
.price {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-item">
  <div class="container-stroke clearfix">
    <div class="element">
      Однокомнатный стандарт
    </div>
    <div class="element">
      <div class="stretch-element">
        <div class="table-cell">
          <div class="line">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="price">1.500 руб/сут</div>
</div>
<div class="product-item">
  <div class="container-stroke clearfix">
    <div class="element">
      Однокомнатный
    </div>
    <div class="element">
      <div class="stretch-element">
        <div class="table-cell">
          <div class="line">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="price">2.500 руб/сут</div>
</div>
```

На [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kzo0zv7s/1/)

Comment: Это слишком сложная разметка, если честно, есть вариант ещё проще, сейчас покажу: http://jsfiddle.net/L2ya3buj/1/

Comment: @Олег Б, мне не очень нравятся вариант, когда на странице блоки перекрывают друг друга с помощью position:absolute, то есть продолжение точек у вас есть, но его не видно из-за  более позиционированного блока. 2. Посмотрите что получится если в правой колонке будет чуть больше текста, цена ведь может быть 900 рублей например или 10000

Comment: Обновил без абсолютного позиционирования.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, в конце концов использую этот вариант, удобно тем, что не надо задавать цвет бэкграунда на блоках с текстом, чтобы перекрыть точки.