# Как сверстать список-содержание с многоточием на конце?

Tags: css

Необходимо сверстать такой список:

Text Text Text Text ..................................................................................123

Text Text Text ..........................................................................................123

Text Text Text Text Text
Text Text Text Text Text Text ..........................123

Text Text Text Text
Text Text Text ..........................................................123

Можно ли это реализовать средствами css. Если да, то как?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Сверстать линии разной длины](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/373335)

Посмотрите ответы в этой теме, тут есть несколько вариантов реализации.

Comment: Добавил еше один вариант в топик по этой ссылке.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь)